# finding numbers with [:digit:] using regex r

Tags: regex, r

I wonder if any regex whizzes can explain this to me:

```
tmp2 <- c("alpha[1]", "be[3]ta", 'gam4ma')
grepl("[0123456789]", tmp2) #[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("[0-9]", tmp2)  #[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
grepl("[:digit:]", tmp2) #[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
grepl("\\[[:digit:]", tmp2) #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
grepl("\\[[0-9]", tmp2) #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Why does using `[:digit:]` not find `alpha[1]` ?

Why does using `\\[[0-9]` find the first two cases, but `\\[[:digit:]` doesn't?

Comment: The square-brackets are part of the regex expression which you then need to be put inside the flanking square-brackets to create a character class. If you had wanted to add some other options say a decimal point to find a decimal fraction (or an ip-address) it would be `"[[:digit:].]+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[:digit:]` is not a valid POSIX class  . You need to inculde `[:digit:]` inside a character class in-order to match digit charcaters . So it would be,

```
grepl("[[:digit:]]", tmp2)
```

> Why does using `\\[[0-9]` find the first two cases

Because there is a `[` exists before atleast one digit.

> but `\\[[:digit:]` doesn't?

I already told that `[:digit:]` is not a POSIX class to match digit chars. 
So try this `\\[[[:digit:]]` .

Comment: I add a reference to [regex101](https://regex101.com/) for OP's reference (note: un-double all instances of `\ ` that you would use in `R`)

Answer (score 1):

The first question is because in R *POSIX character classes* are represented with expressions inside double brackets `[[ ]]`.

The second example you are saying to match all between 0-9, this is achieved with a *A character class* (also called character set) which is a list of characters enclosed by square brackets `[ ]` and which a different concept respect to the previous (the POSIX) class. With the `digit` you fall in the same previous error by not adding the double brackets.

Comment: Well sort of or maybe. That could be read as requiring double brackets around `0-9`.

Comment: Thank you @BondedDust, I've edited. Is it now clear the specification of POSIX classes and a **standard** character classes?